# A consequence of convergence in norm.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-writing

Let $E$ be a measurable set, let $1 \leq p < \infty,$ and let $\{f_{n}\}$ be a sequence in $L^p(E).$ Prove that if $\{f_{n}\}$ converges to a function $f$ in the norm of $L^p(E),$ then  $\{f_{n}\}$ converges to a function $f$ in measure. Is the converse true?

Could anyone give me a hint for this problem?

Comment: use the definition of convergence in measure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converse is not true. Take $f_n(x)=n$ for $0<x<\frac 1 n$ and $0$ for $x \geq \frac  1n$ on $(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure.  $f_n \to 0$ almost everywhere, hence in measure but it does not converge in $L^{1}$.

Direct part: $\mu \{x \in E: |f_n(x)-f(x)| >\epsilon ) \leq \frac 1 {\epsilon^{p}} \int |f_n-f|^{p} d\mu \to 0$.

Comment: In the direct part why your epsilon has a power of $p$ on the right hand side?

Comment: $|f_n(x)-f(x)| \geq \epsilon$ is same as $|f_n(x)-f(x)|^{p} \geq \epsilon^{p}$ and the measure of this is less than or equal to $\frac 1 {\epsilon^{p}} \int |f|^{p}d\mu$.